# retrieve the path of a repo from the "git bash" from windows with right format

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I am trying to retrieve the path of a repository from the "git bash" shell in windows, as follows

```
user@CND7293ZVV MINGW64 /c/Work/git/repository/subfolder (master)
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
C:/Work/git/repository
```

The problem is that I want to use the ouptut path to use it from a bash script, but it is not in bash format. I want to get `/c/Work/git/repository`. Is there any way to get the path in a way that can be used directly in the git bash shell?

extra information: The target is to store that path in a variable to be used inside a bash script, independently of whether I am running bash from a linux terminal, or when I am running from the git bash.

---

**Update**:

To be able to use the command inside the git-bash environment, and also inside native linux bash, we can use the following:

```
REPODIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) 
# If we are inside mingw* environment, then we update the path to proper format
if [[ $(uname) == MINGW* ]] ; then REPODIR=$(cygpath -u "${REPODIR}"); fi; echo ${REPODIR}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running on the Git bash command line, you have an buildin utility with the name [cygpath](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html) that does this:

```
$ cygpath -u "C:/Work/git/repository"
/c/Work/git/repository
```

This can be combined with your existing command to do everything on 1 line:

```
$ cygpath -u "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
/c/Work/git/repository
```

Comment: Hej! This is a very good solution when running inside the git-bash shell. But would it be any way to find a solution that works also for the linux bash? I think about converting if the first letter of the path is not a slash, but keeping the returned path otherwise. Do you know any better solution?

Comment: The only solution I could think of at the moment, is testing if the command cygpath is installed, and if it is installed, just call it, (even on linux, as the `-u` flag doesn't alter the path if it's already a "Unix like" path